# Method Interceptor on private methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

Here is a question: I have method `digest(byte[] data)`. It should be private, because we really don't need it outside a class, however i'll not die if i make it public, if it helps.
The question is: can i somehow attach interceptor to it? The thing is that it is not called like `getBean('MyBean').digest()`, it is called through `getBean('MyBean').sign(data)` where sign is smth like

```
public byte[] sign(byte[] data){
   ...
   b = digest(data);
   ...
   return signature;
}
```

Thx.

Comment: I tried to format your code, but it is still illegal. Please paste it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if the method is public, Spring can't intercept method calls who are made from within the object containing the method. To achieve this, you would have to use AspectJ.

Comment: Correct, Spring AOP works with dynamic proxies, meaning you can only intercept methods that are exposed in an interface and when the proxy is able to delegate directly to the exposed method.

Comment: This only the case for JDK dynamic proxies. Spring AOP can also work with CGLIB subclass proxies, in which case self-invocation of public methods works just fine.

Comment: @Cid54 I am not able to get the meaning of "Spring can't intercept method calls who are made from within the object containing the method" - you mean to say that Spring does not have ability to call one method from another if they r in same class

Comment: @skaffman one method can't call other method in same class when we work with > JDK dynamic proxies ?

Answer (score 1):

Sort of full AspectJ voodoo, you need to make your intercepted method `public`. If you don't want to expose the `digest()` method of your bean as `public`, but still want to apply interceptors, then I suggest refactoring your code to extract the digest logic out into a separate class that implements a new digest interface, and apply the interceptors to that.

It's a bit clumsy, but it does force you to separate your concerns, which is not bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of achieving what you want is to create a Digester class and intercept the calls to it's digest() method:

```
public interface Digester {
  public Foo digest(byte[] data);
}

class DigesterImpl implements Digester {
  public Foo digest(byte[] data) {...}
}
```

Then in your spring code you inject a proxied DigesterImpl to your class and call it:

```
private final Digester digester;

MyClass(Digester digester) {
  this.digester = digester;
}

public byte[] sign(byte[] data){
   ...
   b = digester.digest(data);
   ...
   return signature;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key thing to understand here is that the when using `Aspect` programming the method calls on that object reference will be calls on the proxy, and as such the proxy will be able to delegate to all of the interceptors (advice) that are relevant to that particular method call.

However, once the call has finally reached the target object, any method calls that it may make on itself, **such as Digest(Data), are going to be invoked against the this reference, and not the proxy**.

This has important implications. It means that self-invocation is not going to result in the advice associated with a method invocation getting a chance to execute. But there is a way to do it:

```
public byte[] sign(byte[] data){
   ...
   b = (Digester)AopContext.currentProxy()).Digest(Data);
   ...
   return signature;
}
```

This totally couples your code to `Spring AOP`, and it makes the class itself aware of the fact that it is being used in an AOP context, which flies in the face of AOP.