# @Transactional does not work on method level

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I have a question about Spring 3.2.3 @Transactional annotation.
My Service class looks like this:

```
@Service @Transactional
class InventoryDisclosureBO {

@Autowired InventoryDisclosureDAO inventoryDisclosureDAO;

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger( InventoryDisclosureBO.class);

public void processDisclosureData(InventoryDisclosureStatus data){
  validate(data);
  persist(data);
}

@Transactional(propagation = REQUIRES_NEW)
void persist(InventoryDisclosureStatus data) {
  inventoryDisclosureDAO.setAllInvalid( data.getUnit());
  inventoryDisclosureDAO.insert( data );
}

void validate(InventoryDisclosureStatus data) {
 ...
}
}
```

All works perfectly if I call persist() method. But if I comment out @Transactional at class level - transaction does not start. 
Could anybody tell me why Spring could ignore @Transactional on methol-level only?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot call persist() from processDisclosureData() because it belongs to the same class and it will bypass transactional proxy created by Spring for InventoryDisclosureBO. You should call it from other beans to make @Transactional annotations work. When Spring injects a reference to InventoryDisclosureBO bean to other beans it actually injects a reference to InventoryDisclosureBOProxy which contains transactional logic, eg

```
    class Bean2 {

      @Autowire
      private InventoryDisclosureBO idbo;   <-- Spring will inject a proxy here

      public void persist(InventoryDisclosureStatus data) {
           idbo.persist(data);     <-- now it will work via proxy
      }
...
```

Comment: Thank You Evgeniy, this makes sence! If I put @Transactional on processDisclosureData() method only - it works perfectly.

Comment: 1) can you please eloborate it bit more in your answer "persist() will bypass transactional proxy created by Spring for InventoryDisclosureBO"

Comment: 2) idbo.persist(data);     <-- now it will work via proxy, is it because that we r calling the persist method directly from outside the class? if this is the case, then how it make difference ?

Comment: @Naroji there will be 2 beans in context InventoryDisclosureBO  and InventoryDisclosureBOProxy (real name is different). The latter is created by Spring and contains transactional logic and a reference to InventoryDisclosureBO. When we call InventoryDisclosureBOProxy.persist it starts transaction and then calls InventoryDisclosureBO.persist. If we call InventoryDisclosureBO.persist directly there will be no transaction

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev Thanks, one more question
      private InventoryDisclosureBO idbo;   <-- Spring will inject a proxy here. How you know that Spring will inject a proxy here ?

Comment: @Naroji Spings analizes context.xml, detectes that InventoryDisclosureBO is transactional and creates a proxy for it, then it creates all beans and starts injecting dependencies, everywhere where InventoryDisclosureBO bean reference is needed Spring injects a reference to InventoryDisclosureBOProxy bean

Answer (score 3):

This is related to how spring generates the transactional proxies.

In the case where you have @Transactional at the class level, when you call `InventoryDisclosureBO.processDisclosureData()`, in fact, you're calling a Spring proxy that starts the transaction, and then calls the real implementation.

If you only have @Transaction in persis(), spring doesn't start a transaction when you call `InventoryDisclosureBO.processDisclosureData()`, and then it cannot detect that you've called  `InventoryDisclosureBO.persist()`

So Spring basically ignores the annotation on `persist`, because it cannot add the transactional proxy.

As a rule of thumb, the @Transactional annotation should be on a public method, and hopefully quite high in the call hierarchy (otherwise each persist would end up creating a new transaction)

You might find more information on this other SO question: [Method Interceptor on private methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627005/method-interceptor-on-private-methods) (any non-public methods behave in the same way)

Comment: if @Transactional is applied at class level, only then spring generates the proxy of transaction ?

Comment: if @Transactional is not applied at class level and on processDisclosureData method, then why it cannot detect that you've called InventoryDisclosureBO.persist() ?